# Information about LTSM RNN backpropagation algorithm

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, rnn, backpropagation

I am attempting to make a LTSM RNN in python from scratch and I have completed the code for forward pass but I am struggling to find a clear outline of the equations I need to calculate to get the gradients using back-propagation. Is there any straightforward resource that I can learn these equations from and how to implement them(as my programming skills are limited)?
Thanks for any help,

The notation for my code is that; hu is the update gate, hf is the forget gate and ho is the output gate.

```
def forward(inp,target):
    loss = 0
    c_temp,c,x,a,y,prob = {},{},{},{},{},{}
    c_old = {}
    c[-1] = np.zeros((hidden_size,1))
    a[-1] = np.zeros((hidden_size,1))
    for t in range(len(inp)):
        x[t] = np.zeros((vocab_size,1))
        x[t][inp[t]] = 1
        X = np.concatenate((x[t],a[t-1]))
        c_temp[t] = tanh(wc @ X  + bc)
        hf[t] = sigmoid( wf @ X + bf)
        hu[t] = sigmoid( wu @ X + bu)
        ho[t] = sigmoid(wo @ X + bo)

        c[t] = hu*c_temp[t] + hf * c[t-1]
        a[t] = ho * tanh(c[t])

        y[t] = wy @ a[t]  + by
        prob[t] = softmax(y[t])
        loss += loss(prob[t],target[t])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/08/12/lstm-backprop/) is a good tutorial on LSTM from scratch with forward and backward pass.

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that when you update parameters you update for example the 'weight1' with the derivative of the error with respect to weight1?

Comment: Yes, that's correct